# Day "1" of "DAY_OF_WEEK" does not coincide with Monday

Tags: java, android-studio, calendar, java-time, dayofweek

I run this test application

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int currentDayNumber = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    Log.d("currentDayNumber",String.valueOf(currentDayNumber));

}
```

The day on which this test was run was a Thursday, and "currentDayNumber" gave 5, which means that "DAY_OF_WEEK" (days of week numbered from 1 to 7) starts on **Sunday**.

This is contrary to what the Android Developer pages say (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/DayOfWeek), that by default the number 1 of DAY_OF_WEEK is set to **Monday**.

Any explanation for this discrepancy?

Answer (score 3):

Your documentation link points to `java.time.DayOfWeek`, which is indeed Monday-based. But your code appears to be using `java.util.Calendar` which is [Sunday-based](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SUNDAY). You can use `LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek()` to get a `java.time.DayOfWeek` for the current time from the system clock in the default time-zone.

Comment: Very thoughtful to make different dating systems that use the same verbal reference ("Day Of Week") within java start on different days. To keep developers on their toes, I suppose. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Evenness to be fair, Sunday is considered to be the first day of the week in a big chunk of the world, America included.

Comment: @Evenness yes it can be a bit confusing... The Calendar API dates all the way back to JDK 1.1, which was released back in 1997. Time API (JSR 310) is much newer and was introduced in Java 8 in 2014. The change of weekday bias is due to Time API being built on ISO 8601 standard, where weekdays run from Monday to Sunday.

Comment: @Evenness This seems to happen a lot. In `Date` years were 1900-based, in `GregorianCalendar` they follow human numbers. In `GregorianCalendar` months are 0-based (contrary to human numbering), in java.time they are 1-based. I generally find it good that they put something better instead of the old confusing classes. No one should use `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` anymore anyway.